# Get local time in php

Tags: php, time, local

Why does the procedural code not get the same result as the Object-oriented code? I have legacy code which requires procedural result. Note I have a work-around but I'd like to understand why the Procedural Code doesn't get the local time.

```
`$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
 $now = strtotime($dt->format('m/d/Y, H:i:s')); //This is a work-around which works
 $oo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$now);
 //Procedural Code
 $now = date_timestamp_get($dt);
 $pc = date('Y.m.d H:i:s',$now);        `
```

Comment: Well, you specified the timezone in the OO one, but not in the procedural one. So unless you're running this on a machine which happens to already be configured to the same timezone, then you won't get the same result from both of them. e.g. my computer's timezone is GMT so the procedural code gives me a time 8 hours later than the OO code

Comment: P.S. re your "this is a workaround which works" comment...it's unclear what you mean by that. It doesn't seem to have any effect...that is completely redundant code which takes a formatted date, parses it back into a timestamp string, and then re-formats it. You could achieve the exact same output with just `echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` - demo: https://3v4l.org/QLVgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the comments, courtesy [Adyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson)

> Well, you specified the timezone in the OO one, but not in the
> procedural one. So unless you're running this on a machine which
> happens to already be configured to the same timezone, then you won't
> get the same result from both of them. e.g. my computer's timezone is
> GMT so the procedural code gives me a time 8 hours later than the OO
> code

Comment: I didn't realize one could set the timezone in PHP_INI file. That solves my issue.